# Sentence splitting (using conjunction and punctuation) Error: "None" in python

Tags: python, split, sentence

I want to split a sentence. When it finds conjunction(and, or, but) and punctuation(','), I want to split them and return the previous part of the sentence. I tried but I faced a problem. I can correctly split them but at the end, I got an extra line and it was **"None"**. Here is my code:

```
conj =['and','but','or']
punctuation_lst =['.','!',',',':',';','?']
conj= conj+punctuation_lst

txt='i eat rice , food and many things but service is good'


def conj_based_split(txt):
  lst=[]
  a=1
  for word in txt.split():
    if word not in conj:
      lst.append(word)
    elif (word in conj):
      sent=' '.join(lst)
      print(sent)
      lst.clear()
    if (a==len(txt.split())):
      if(len(lst)):
        sent=' '.join(lst)
        print(sent)
    a=a+1

print(conj_based_split(txt))
```

and output is:

```
i eat rice
food
many things
service is good
None
```

When txt is: **'i eat rice, food and many things but service is good',** this code can not split this 'i eat rice, food' part. Expected that it gives: 'i eat rice' and 'food'.

Where is the problem in the code? and How can I remove this "None"? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. The problem is:

You have a function and in this function you print something. When you call the function you print its output too. However this function returns nothing (None). So just change

```
print(conj_based_split(txt))
```

to

```
conj_based_split(txt)
```

**Update after update in question:**

Your code is not general. You split the string with whitespaces and you consider commas have whitespace on both sides.

So if you change your string from

```
 'i eat rice, food and many things but service is good'
```

to

```
 'i eat rice , food and many things but service is good'
```

it might work. But you might want to change the logic. Because the correct way to write commas is `"something, other thing"`.

Comment: thanks. it works.  But when txt is: 'i eat rice, food and many things but service is good', this code can not split this 'i eat rice, food' part. Expected that it gives: 'i eat rice' and 'food'. Where is the problem in the code?